# Figuring Out What's Going on This Code (Recursive Descent Case Study)

Tags: c++, iterator, stl-algorithm

I am reading a Data Structures and Algorithms book and there is a case study on recursion, specifically a parser that uses recursive descent. I'm a bit new to C++ (I'm learning it on the side and as I go with Stanley B. Lippman's C++ Primer 5th edition).

I'm a bit stuck on code and am trying to make sense of it. Is what I've written at the bottom (bulleted points) accurate descriptions of what is happening in the functions? I would post the header, but it's a bit too long, you can probably find it online if you search "Data Structures
and Algorithms in C++ by Adam Drozdek - interpreter.h".

```
double Statement::findValue(char* id) {
    IdNode tmp(id);
    list<IdNode>::iterator i = find(idList.begin(), idList.end(), tmp);
    if (i != idList.end())
        return i->value;
    else
        issueError("Unknown variable");
    return 0;
}

void Statement::processNode(char* id, double e) {
    IdNode tmp(id, e);
    list<IdNode>::iterator i = find(idList.begin(), idList.end(), tmp);
    if (i != idList.end())
        i->value = e;
    else
        idList.push_front(tmp);
}
```

findValue()

- Looks for a value for a certain variable
- Uses an iterator i so that it can traverse the list
- Looks for tmp using find()
- If i doesn't equal the value at the end of the list, return it
- Other wise, the variable cannot be found

processNode()

- Processes nodes by using an iterator i
- Looks for a variable that matches tmp
- Finds the variable and sets it's value to the value of e
- Other wise, store variable on to idList to be evaluated later

Comment: You should step through your code using a debugger so that you know what you're code is doing.  Also, it isn't a good idea to write code and not know, 100%, what the code *you wrote* is actually doing or is supposed to do.  Imagine if you had a bug and you yourself wasn't sure what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: End of the list is returned for not found, so "If i doesn't equal the value at the end of the list, return it" is better worded as "If the named item was found, return its value."

Comment: I wouldn't use a linked list for this, by the way. A `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` would be a better fit. Since this is an Algorithms and Data structures course you're probably expected to do the algorithms the hard way, though. Remember that which does not kill you makes you stronger, so happy suffering!

Comment: I've only worked with ANTLR for recursive descent parsing, so I'm really winging it here. My guess is it's at the "statement" parser rule. This rule reads a token (IdNode) from the input stream and checks if it's a valid next token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function that accepts a pointer to char (likely it's an array) and returns a `double`:

```
double Statement::findValue(char* id) {
```

Create a temporary (will die at 'return') of type `IdNode` based on that pointer:

```
IdNode tmp(id);
```

Use a (`std::` I guess, but it could be any function with the same features) function that looks for `tmp` inside the container `idList`. The result is an interator `i`, which must be of the same type of that one used by the container:

```
list<IdNode>::iterator i = find(idList.begin(), idList.end(), tmp);
```

Check if something is found. `idList.end()` means "one past end", **beyond** the last item in the container:

```
if (i != idList.end())
```

Return the member `value` (which is part of `IdNode`) for the item found. If `value` is not a `double` then convert to it.

```
    return i->value;
```

Otherwise, call `issueError` function.

```
else
    issueError("Unknown variable");
```

Exit function, returning a `double` with value = 0:

```
return 0;
}
```

---

Same, but: this function accepts two parameters and returns nothing:

```
void Statement::processNode(char* id, double e) {
```

Same, but: `IdNode` constructor uses two parameters:

```
IdNode tmp(id, e);
```

Same

```
list<IdNode>::iterator i = find(idList.begin(), idList.end(), tmp);
```

Same

```
if (i != idList.end())
```

Now, modify the item found. Just update `value` member:

```
    i->value = e;
```

Otherwise, **add** `tmp`, insert it at the very begining of `idList` container.

```
else
    idList.push_front(tmp);
```

Exit function:

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is mostly right.  I'll describe it statement by statement
in somewhat more precise terms.

```
double Statement::findValue(char* id) {
    IdNode tmp(id);
```

This constructs a variable named `tmp` using the string passed in.  (Well, I presume `id` is a string.  In C, it's common to pass a pointer to the beginning of a zero-terminated array of characters when you want to pass a string.  In C++, the same thing was common, but it's becoming less common now that we have better string and range types in the standard library.  But not every `char *` is a string.  It might just be a pointer to a single character.  Here though, the context strong suggests it's a string.)

```
    list<IdNode>::iterator i = find(idList.begin(), idList.end(), tmp);
```

Uses the `std::find` algorithm to search the range of elements from the beginning of the `idList` to the end for an element that equals `tmp`.

Note the `idList.end()` is an iterator that indicates the actual end of the list rather than the last item in the list.  You can think of it as one element beyond the last element in the list.  Iterator ranges (and array indices) in C and C++ are typically inclusive of the first value and exclusive of the second.  So `find` will start with the first element and continue up *to* (but not through) the end of the list.

It's not shown here, but I assume there's an overload for `operator==(const idNode &, const idNode &)` that returns true if the names of the two `idNodes` match, regardless of whether the value fields match.

If there's no match in the range, then `std::find` is going to return the end iterator.  If there is a match, it's going to return an iterator that references the matching element.  So ...

```
    if (i != idList.end())
        return i->value;
    else
      issueError("Unknown variable");
```

This returns the value field of the match (if there is one) or it calls `issueError` if there isn't.

```
    return 0;
}
```

In the latter case, assuming `issueError` returns and doesn't terminate the program or throw an exception, the function will return a value of 0 (which, because the return type is a double, will be implicitly converted to 0.0).

`processNode` is nearly identical except that it sets the value in the found node rather than returning it.